# send mail in android via java mail AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, sendmail

i want to send email in android in my app by javamail and i get AuthenticationFailedException can anyone help me
i use this link for sen mail 
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: copy and pate the code in that link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthenticationFailedException means the server thinks you've supplied the wrong username or password, or even though you've supplied the right username and password, the server still doesn't want to allow you to login.  Why not?  Well, the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) might provide clues.  If you're using Gmail, you'll need to [enable less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: my problem solved by enable less secure app in gmail